# How can I read JSON code in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba

I have JSON data in this form
[{"word":"something", "id":1023]
How can I get the value of word from the JSON data using Visual Basic?
Thanks.

Comment: Use a JSON parser - Tim Hall wrote a pretty nice one, it's [on GitHub](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Answer (score 1):

Grab a copy of this [project](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON), add it to your VBA project. You'll need to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` for this to work as the results from the parsed string get stored in a Dictionary. Once that's done, you can parse JSON, like this:

```
Sub ParseSomeJson()
    Dim jsonString As String
    Dim json As Object
    jsonString = "{""word"":""something"", ""id"":1023}" 'I adjusted this 
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonString)
    Debug.Print json("word"), json("id")
End Sub
```

You'll get back:

```
something      1023
```

Comment: Note that Tim Hall also wrote a drop-in replacement for `Scripting.Dictionary` (also found under that VBA-TOOLS GitHub org), that works off the Scripting Runtime on Windows, and works on a Mac.